# Converting a switched outlet to always on, using switch for new ceiling fan

Tags: electrical

I am trying to install a new ceiling fan in a bedroom where there currently is no light fixture in the ceiling at all, and have that fan be controlled by an existing light switch in the room that,  right now, switches an outlet.  I want to remove that outlet from the switch, leave it always on like any standard receptacle,  and wire the light switch to the new ceiling fan.
The light switch has one black wire and one yellow wire.  The yellow connects to the outlet, and this is the ONLY wire connecting the switch to the outlet.  The black wire from the switch runs to a bundle of 3 black wires that are in the outlet junction box but NOT connected at all to the outlet.   The outlet only has two white wires in its back which run to other outlets in the room.  There are no black wires in the switched outlet.  Thus, only that single yellow wire that connects the switch to the outlet serves as the power.
Any thoughts????

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the switch box please?

Comment: How do you plan to switch on the light?

Comment: What country is this in?

Comment: Hi everyone, I don't have a photo but the switch box just has a black wire and yellow wire,  that's it.  I believe the black wire is always hot and the yellow is a hot wire too when the switch is on.  There is no neutral wire.   I have done some additional research and I believe the solution to my problem is that I have to rewire the outlet and convert that yellow wire to be neutral by tying it to the other neutrals.  Doing so will then provide a neutral in my light switch box,  and I can then run and connect romex to the switch box

Comment: Could the yellow wire have originally been white, and turned yellow with age?

Comment: Tyson, no I don't think so. It's definitely a yellow wire.  My understanding is that back when the house was built in the 60's, a neutral wasn't required to a switch,  and my setup is very common.